# Constructor method called twice when using top-level variable

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new with `dart` syntax.

I'm trying to use top-level variable.

But I got issue `// STEP 3 : THIS CONSTRUCTOR CALLED TWICE AudioPlayerTask()` in `AudioPlayerTask` class.

It happened in `return audioPlayerTask; // STEP 2 : WHEN RETURN THIS VALUE`

I have no idea with it.

People who know,

Please tell me how to I avoid it called twice. (I expect it called once.)

Thanks,

**AudioPlayerPage.dart**

```
// top-level variable
// STEP 1 : CONSTRUCTOR MEDTHOD CALL FIRST TIME
final AudioPlayerTask audioPlayerTask = AudioPlayerTask();
```

**AudioPlayerTask.dart**

```
class AudioPlayerTask extends BackgroundAudioTask {
  
  // STEP 3 : THIS CONSTRUCTOR CALLED TWICE.
  AudioPlayerTask() {
    print('AudioPlayerTask() : Constructor()');
  }
}
```

**AudioPlayerBloc.dart**

```
class AudioPlayerBloc {

/*
* Feature : Start background service to play and show notification
* */
Future startService() async {
  if (!AudioService.connected) {
    await AudioService.connect();

    print('AudioService.start()');

    await AudioService.start(
      backgroundTaskEntrypoint: audioPlayerTaskEntryPoint,
      androidNotificationChannelName: 'Nhaccuatui',
      androidNotificationColor: 0x00AEEF,
      androidNotificationIcon: 'mipmap/ic_launcher',
    );
  }
}

// top-level function.
void audioPlayerTaskEntryPoint() async {
  print('AudioServiceBackground.run() :');

  AudioServiceBackground.run(() {
    return audioPlayerTask; // STEP 2 : WHEN RETURN THIS VALUE, IT MAKES THE CONSTRUCTOR CALL AGAIN
  });
}


}
```

**pubspec.yaml**

```
name: flutter
description: Flutter
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.9.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  audio_service: ^0.15.3
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0
  rxdart: ^0.24.1

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  build_runner: ^1.10.4

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
```

**UPDATE** Follow @dm_tr suggestion, it can accessed as global variable, but it's value (`audioPlayerTask` ) always be null. I missed something?

**main.dart**

```
AudioPlayerTask audioPlayerTask;

void main() {
  // If you're running an application and need to access the binary messenger 
  // before `runApp()` has been called (for example, during plugin initialization),
  // then you need to explicitly call the `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()` first.
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  audioPlayerTask = AudioPlayerTask();

  runApp(App());
}

// top-level function.
void audioPlayerTaskEntryPoint() async {
  print(
      'audioPlayerTask = $audioPlayerTask'  // THIS VALUE IS NULL
  );

  if (audioPlayerTask != null) {
    print('AudioServiceBackground.run() :');
    
    AudioServiceBackground.run(() => audioPlayerTask);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create `empty constructor` (default constructor) in dart. Just declare the class and you can create it's instance anywhere

Comment: In case I want to use this variable as global?
`final AudioPlayerTask audioPlayerTask = AudioPlayerTask();` How I can keep this?

Comment: Declare the variable in `main.dart` file before `void main()` like this `AudioPlayerTask audioPlayerTask` and initialize it in the main method `audioPlayerTask = AudioPlayerTask();`. This way, it's considered as variable global and is accessible in every page of your project

Comment: I applied already, but its value always be null in method `audioPlayerTaskEntryPoint `. You can see my updated question for more detail?